# How to apply an regular expression for below pattern?

Tags: regex

I have some string data, 
I want to apply a regular expression and to filter out some keywords from data.

For ex, String Data:

```
new id for MS is amsd2a-bc-001-oa2 please provide more input etc..
```

Now I have to extract the ID **amsd2a-bc-001-oa2** from the above string.

I'm using regular expression(mentioned below) to extract ID from data.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,6}-bc-[0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]
```

above regular expression is working but its matching the ID's like **amsd2a-bc-001**

how to make this regular expression to match only for specific pattern.
Ex : RegEx to match "*amsd2a-bc-001-oa2*" but not for "*amsd2a-bc-001*".

Comment: What programming language regex is this?

Comment: What environment are you in? Your examples work as expected in [this tool](http://regexr.com/).

Comment: It will catch something like "amsd2a-bc-001-oa2-oa2" if that is a problem, not something like  "amsd2a-bc-001".

Comment: I'm using RegEx parser which is compatible with Java & perl

Comment: Environment: I'm working on tool based application, which is compatible with Java and Perl RegEX

Comment: `([a-z0-9\-]{17})`

Comment: I need RegEx to match something like "amsd2a-bc-001-oa2-oa2", but currently used RegEx is matching pattern like "amsd2a-bc-001". so it should not match words like "amsd2a-bc-001".

Comment: What you say is not true, [your pattern matches only expected substrings](https://regex101.com/r/6FFy1c/1).

Answer (score 0):

I checked for the mentioned string and regular expression in Java..
I got proper output as 'amsd2a-bc-001-oa2'

Below is the code i used:

```
   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
   import java.util.regex.Pattern;

  class MyClass {
   public static void main( String args[] ) {

   // String to be scanned 
   String line = "nnew id for MS is amsd2a-bc-001-oa2 please provide more input etc";
   String pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,6}-bc-[0-9]{3}-[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]";


   // Create a Pattern object
   Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

   // Now create matcher object.
   Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
   m.find( );
   System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );

  }
}
```

I think you are missing something